# How can i add more information to pins in UIMapView

Tags: ios, mkmapview

Im new to developing for iOS and i just got my dev account and am starting to get into more difficult things. Well anyways ive learned how to add a UIMapView and how to have it switch between the different views and how to set pins with a tittle and sub tittle but i want to make it so when you see the pin drop you see the tittle and then on the left theres a little arrow that you tap and it takes you to a page with more information like how to a button that you tap that takes you to the maps app and gives you directions to the location or you can have more information in the page. Basically how it looks in the maps app on iOS when you search for a location and a bunch pop up. So my overall question is how can i add a more information tab to the drop pin on my map view?

Answer (score 1):

This can be achieve with the help of **mapView viewForAnnotation:** delegate method. All you have to do is create a button and assign this as the **rightCalloutAccessoryView**. A sample code is given below

```
- (MKAnnotationView *) mapView:(MKMapView *)mapView viewForAnnotation:(id <MKAnnotation>) annotation{
    MKPinAnnotationView *annView=[[MKPinAnnotationView alloc] initWithAnnotation:annotation reuseIdentifier:@"currentloc"];
    annView.pinColor = MKPinAnnotationColorGreen;

    UIButton *advertButton = [UIButton buttonWithType:UIButtonTypeDetailDisclosure];
    advertButton.frame = CGRectMake(0, 0, 23, 23);
    advertButton.contentVerticalAlignment = UIControlContentVerticalAlignmentCenter;
    advertButton.contentHorizontalAlignment = UIControlContentHorizontalAlignmentCenter;

    //[advertButton setImage:[UIImage imageNamed:@"button_right.png"] forState:UIControlStateNormal];
    [advertButton addTarget:self action:@selector(showLinks:) forControlEvents:UIControlEventTouchUpInside];

    annView.rightCalloutAccessoryView = advertButton;

    annView.animatesDrop=TRUE;
    annView.canShowCallout = YES;
    annView.calloutOffset = CGPointMake(-5, 5);
    return annView;
}
```

inside your target method **showLinks:**, you can add the code for navigation to the infopage

```
-(void)showLinks:(UIButton*)sender  {
     //do the stuffs for navigation

}
```

Comment: @preetam yes sure. why not? find the link for google map SDK for IOS https://developers.google.com/maps/documentation/ios/start

Comment: no. apple will not reject apps using google map sdk. this is an example https://itunes.apple.com/in/app/zomato/id434613896

Comment: let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/41529/discussion-between-manujmv-and-preetam)